# how to change my Vticker default direction(sliding up) into right to left

Tags: jquery

```
$(function() {
 $('#example').vTicker();


   $('#example1').vTicker({
   speed: 500,
       pause: 3000,
       showItems: 3,
       animation: 'fade',
       mousePause: false,
       height: 0,
       direction: 'left'
   });
});
```

Comment: read the documentation for the plugin `vTicker`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve it at this moment since from the **[docs](http://www.jugbit.com/jquery-vticker-vertical-news-ticker/)** , `Vticker` only support `up` and `down` for the `direction` value.

So you're probably need to extend the core function inside `Vticker` script or try to find another plugin which fulfil your requirement.